# What's the difference between Node.js' Cluster module and Learnboost's Cluster module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing, npm

Node.js itself has a core module called Cluster ( ref: http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.3/api/cluster.html) and Learnboost has released a module that is also named Cluster (ref: http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/  https://github.com/LearnBoost/cluster).

How do these two compare? Are they related in someway?

Comment: The core Cluster module was removed from node around version .4 and was only recently re-added with version .8. The LearnBoost version may have been created to fill the void in the mean-time.

Unfortunately, I'm unsure how they actually compare.

Answer (score 3):

Nick Hagianis alredy said it, the cluster module of node.js was temporarily removed. As far as I can see the LearnBoost cluster module isn't developed actively any more. The issues list of the LearnBoost module is quite long.

The LearnBoost module has some features as zero-downtime restart that the internal module doesn't offer. But I'm not sure if it still works with current (0.8.x) versions of node. If you need similar features you may take a look at the [Forever](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

The [cluster module](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) has now been added back in to the core set of modules.